# Using passport Js i can register a user creating a session table. Req.isAuthenticated comes back false in custom auth function

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, passport.js, express-session

I want to know why req.isAuthenticated is false in custom auth function.

Tried Searching the problem on google. Most solutions were to correctly configure when you should be calling cookie parse and passport.initialize() and passport.session(). Also, having the same passport for cookie-parser and express-session and server restarts.

//server.js
//

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const db = require('./models');
const routes = require('./controller/controller');
//Authethication packages
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
//serve up static assets production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  /*app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join((__dirname = './client/build/index.html')));*/
  /*const index = path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(index);*/
  //});
}
//build mode local
/*app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/public/index.html'));
});*/
//session options
function extendedDefaultFields(defaults, session) {
  return {
    data: defaults.data,
    expires: defaults.expires
  };
}
//
const cookieExpirationDate = new Date();
const cookieExpirationDays = 365;
cookieExpirationDate.setDate(
  cookieExpirationDate.getDate() + cookieExpirationDays
);

const sessionOptions = {
  key: 'userId',
  secret: /*process.env.SECRET*/ 'foo',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: cookieExpirationDate, //1 month
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
    httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
  },
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: db,
    table: 'Session',
    checkExpirationInterval: 20 * 23 * 60 * 1000,
    expiration: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //1 month
    extendedDefaultFields: extendedDefaultFields
  })
};
//cookieparse
const secret = 'foo';
app.use(cookieParser(secret));
//static file declaration
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
//middleware to extract requests and exposing to req, without manually searching for them.
//extented keyword allow you to have nested objects sent
//dont need bodyparser package. Express has it included now after version 4.16.0
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//express session. Options in object defined from line 29.
app.use(session(sessionOptions));
//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session(sessionOptions));
app.use(routes);
//use routes when made and connect to mysql
db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
});`


///
//routes
const db = require('../models');
const bycrpt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const saltRounds = 10;
router.get('/api/users', (req, res, next) => {
  db.User.findAll({})
    .then(dbFindAll => {
      return res.json(dbFindAll);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error) {
        res.json(error);
      }
    });
});
router.post('/api/newuser', (req, res, next) => {
  //strip tags afterwards.
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password } = req.body;
  //strip html tags and remove uneccessary white spaces
  const stripTagsFunction = myString => {
    return myString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
  };
  if (first_name && last_name && email && password) {
    bycrpt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
      if (!err) {
        db.User.create({
          first_name: stripTagsFunction(first_name.split(' ').join('')),
          last_name: stripTagsFunction(last_name.split(' ').join('')),
          email: stripTagsFunction(email.split(' ').join('')),
          password: hash
        })
          .then(created => {
            const userId = created.id;
            if (!created) {
              return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'An error has occured. User has not been saved'
              });
            } else if (created && typeof userId !== 'undefined') {
              req.login(userId, {}, error => {
                // console.log('req.user: ', req);
                console.log('hi: ', req.session.passport.user);
                console.log('is authenticated: ', req.isAuthenticated());
                if (!error) {
                  return res.json({
                    success: true,
                    data: created,
                    message: 'User successfully created'
                  });
                } else {
                  return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    data: 'corrupted seralization',
                    message: 'User created Successfully, but not seralized'
                  });
                }
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            if (error) {
              return res.json({ success: false, errors: error });
            }
          });
      } else {
        res.json({ success: false, errors: err, message: 'Hash Failed' });
      }
    });
  } else {
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ success: false, message: 'Error Missing Parameters' });
  }
});
router.get('/test', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
  return res.send('hi');
});
passport.serializeUser(function(userId, done) {
  console.log('from seralized userId: ', userId);
  done(null, userId);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
  db.User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('\n\n\n\nFound User\n\n\n\n');
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      console.log('Unable to deseralize');
    }
  });
});
//authentication middleware
function authenticationMiddleware() {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.cookies);
    console.log('is authenticated middleware: ', req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    } else {
      return res
        .json({
          success: false,
          data: 'unable to login',
          message: 'unsuccessfull login process'
        })
        .status(404);
    }
  };
}

//passport
module.exports = router;
```

Results: console.log(req.session) in authenticationMiddleWare function to show property passport. However it does not. Also, req.cookie is coming back as an empty object. 
Expected: req.session come back with passport property, like it does in req.login from my register route.

Comment: here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/surajjagdev/Chat-a-Mate

Comment: Solved. Cookie was being saved on front-end port and I was hitting the backend directly so cookie was not being read.